# The creation of Sun and Earth as per Holy-Quran

Tags: quran, creation

According to the Holy Quran,  earth was created in 5-6 days. but sun was created after 3 days then how Quran come to know that earth was created in 6 *days* without sun(days was counted w/o sun) ?

Looking for answer with authentic reference.

**Update**

After more research I found that there is no place where this is mentioned that Sun was created after earth. 
 And as stated by Azad below,  in fact what is mentioned is as below:

> And We did certainly create the heavens and earth and what is between them in six days, and there touched Us no weariness.

from which it cannot be concluded that Sun was created after earth.

Answer (score 2):

According to Holy Qur'an, Allah(SWT) created heavens and earth and what is between them in *six* days:

[[**50:38**]](http://quran.com/50/38)

> And We did certainly create the heavens and earth and what is between
>   them in six days, and there touched Us no weariness.

This is in general counting, but in surah `Fussilat`, Allah(SWT) showing us that the first 4 days created Earth, and the other two days was for *heavens and what is between them*:

[[**41:9**]](http://quran.com/41/9)

> Say, "Do you indeed disbelieve in He who created the earth in two days
>   and attribute to Him equals? That is the Lord of the worlds."

[[**41:10**]](http://quran.com/41/10)

> And He placed on the earth firmly set mountains over its surface, and
>   He blessed it and determined therein its [creatures'] sustenance in
>   four days without distinction - for [the information] of those who
>   ask.

[[**41:12**]](http://quran.com/41/12)

> And He completed them as seven heavens within two days and inspired in
>   each heaven its command...

---

Above verses shows that your understanding is wrong(*earth was created in 5-6 days. but sun was created after 3 days*).

All of them created in only *`six`* days, there is no `5-6` days for earth then `3` days for sun.

Except earth, all other heavens including the sun(which is part of our heaven) created in 2 days.

Allah knows the best.

Comment: Can you cite an ayah that says Sun is a part of heaven?

Comment: @gpuguy: What do you exactly mean? There is another peruse behind this question, can I know please?

Comment: Since you said "sun(which is part of our heaven)", so the question arises where is this written.

Comment: @gpuguy: good question, I think we must find out is it's part of our heaven, Allah only give an ayah which means a path to find out, *`And We did certainly create the heavens and earth and what is between them`*, you see, *between them*, what's between them, starts, galaxies....etc.

Answer (score -3):

The ratio of the age of the Universe to that of the Earth from the Holy Quran
There is no God but Allah. The God says in the Holy Quran in Surat Al-Araf Ch. 7 : V. 54 what means “Indeed, your Lord is Allah, Who created the Heavens and the Earth in six days and then established Himself above the Throne” and in Surat Fussilat Ch. 41 : V. 9 what means “Say, do you indeed disbelieve in He Who created the Earth in two days and attribute to Him equals ? That is the Lord of the words”. Scientifically speaking, these meanings seem to indicate that the 7 Heavens are 6 days old, while the Earth is 2 days old according to the cosmic calendar in the Holy Quran, which means also that the ratio of the age of the 7 Heavens to that of the Earth is equal to 3, that is R = T / t = 6 / 2 = 3, in where T is the age of the 7 Heavens and t is the age of the Earth. Now, if one tries to calculate the same ratio using the current measurements of the age of the Universe which is T = 13.799 ± 0.021 Gyrs and that of the Earth which is t = 4.54 ± 0.05 Gyrs, this gives that this ratio is equal to 3.04, that is R = T / t = 13.799 * 10^9 yrs / 4.54 * 10^9 yrs = 3.04. It turns out with my surprise that the number of verses in which the creation of the 7 Heavens and the Earth in 6 days is mentioned 3 times in the Holy Quran (Surah Al-Araf Ch. 7 : V. 54, Surah Al Hadid Ch. 57 : V. 4, and Surah Yunes Ch. 10 : V. 3), and the number of verses in which the creation of the 7 Heavens and the Earth and what is between them in 6 days is also mentioned 3 times in the Holy Quran (Surah Qaf Ch. 50 : V. 38, Surah I-sajdah Ch. 32 : V. 4, and Surah Al-Furqan Ch. 25 : V. 59). This is not a simple coincidence but instead a scientific evidence that the Holy Quran is a revelation from the God to the prophet Mohamed (peace and blessings of Allah be upon Him) about 15 centuries ago. It is important to note that the days of creation of the 7 Heavens and the Earth have nothing to do with our reckoning on the Earth nor with the days of Allah on the Siderat Al-Montaha in where the Throne of Allah is located. But, Allah knows best.